# How do I setup an html + javascript project in Visual Studio 2019 and use IIS Express

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2019, iis-express

I'm trying to debug an html + javascript app and getting CORS errors so I need a local webserver.  How can I setup a project in VS 2019 to debug html + javascript using IIS Express?  Everything I seem to find on this topic leads to debugging using Chrome or Edge which doesn't help because of the CORS issue.

Comment: You debug the client side using a browser such as chrome or edge. So that part of the advice is accurate. Using visual studio to debug the JavaScript part is overkill. Visual studio could be used to debug your server side code if it's written in a compatible language.

Comment: But if you just want a local webserver to serve static html pages then just install IIS (or Apache or some other lightweight webserver) on your machine.

Comment: A local server can also have CORS issue, and IIS Express even makes it harder to work on as it does not have a CORS module like full IIS. More info can be found in https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-install-microsoft-cors-module-for-iis-express-7ac24e4c3bc4